# density plot shows fringes between points (R ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2, probability-density

Hi my density plot shows fringes/dips between points when there are only several points, see this picture:

http://www.imagesup.net/?di=3141413124212

```
# show fringes    
test = as.data.frame( sample(0:5,1000,replace=T) ) 
colnames(test) = c('mon')
ggplot(test, aes(x=mon)) + geom_density(binwidth=1, size=1)

# normal
test = as.data.frame( sample(0:20,1000,replace=T) ) 
colnames(test) = c('mon')
ggplot(test, aes(x=mon)) + geom_density(binwidth=1, size=1)
```

Anybody know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the `adjust=` parameter to change the bandwidth used to estimate the density: `ggplot(test, aes(x=mon)) + geom_density(binwidth=1, size=1, adjust=2)`. As the `?stat_density` help page suggets, check out the parameters to [density](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/stats/density)